# Issue with single phase short circuit current in three phase transformer Y-YN . Why is there no symmetry in the primary currents L2 and L3?

Tags: electric-circuits

We are having issues with an experiment with a transformer in Y-YN configuration.
We have a symmetrical three phase system on the primary and experiment with a short circuit (resistive load added) in L1 in the secondary.

The theory for short circuits with symmetrical components states that I0 = I1 = I2 = 1p.u. therefore in the secondary system there is IL1 = 3p.u. ; IL2 = 0 ; IL3 = 0.

The transformer configuration has open contacts for the zero primary system so in the primary system there should only be I1' = I2' = 1p.u. I0' = 0. Therefore the currents should be IL1' = 2p.u. ; IL2' = -1 ; IL3 = -1.

However the measured IL2' and the measured IL3' are not equal. The current phasor clockwise to the short circuit phase is always larger than the current of the third phasor not matter in which strand we place the short circuit.

How can we explain that behaviour ?